# Installing javaws on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, java, java-web-start

My jvm installation apparently does not contain javaws.

`sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep ^java
java                           manual   /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle/bin/java
javac                          manual   /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle/bin/javac
javadoc                        manual   /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle/bin/javadoc
javap                          manual   /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle/bin/javap`

I have used both the ppa and a direct install from oracle here:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html

and 
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

I need javaws to launch a jnlp file.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

(NOTE: I tried v11 and v8 ppa appears unavailable due to new licensing.)

Answer (score 11):

`javaws` is included in the package `icedtea-netx`.

`sudo apt install icedtea-netx`

From [here](https://cornis-techblog.de/hp-ilo4-fernwartung-unter-linux-benutzen/).